# Tried to access method JavaXMember.getJavaType() from class JsonTypeDescriptor

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-types

I had a working Spring Boot project which is using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate as a JPA implementation. Some day running this project I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXMember.getJavaType()Ljava/lang/reflect/Type; from class com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JsonTypeDescriptor
```

Here is full stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXMember.getJavaType()Ljava/lang/reflect/Type; from class com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JsonTypeDescriptor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at kz.rs.promo.PromoApp.main(PromoApp.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXMember.getJavaType()Ljava/lang/reflect/Type; from class com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JsonTypeDescriptor
    at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JsonTypeDescriptor.setParameterValues(JsonTypeDescriptor.java:69)
    at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType.setParameterValues(JsonBinaryType.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.injectParameters(TypeFactory.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.type(TypeFactory.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.byClass(TypeFactory.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.heuristicType(TypeResolver.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

I have no idea what caused the exception, I haven't edit configuration (application property file, pom.xml, env variables). This is a partial list of dependencies, related to hibernate, listed using the command `mvn dependency:list`:

```
com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:jar:2.19.2:compile
org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.2.12.Final:compile
org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:5.2.12.Final:compile
org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.12.Final:compile
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5:jar:2.8.10:compile
com.hazelcast:hazelcast-hibernate52:jar:1.2.2:compile
```

Java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_302"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.302.08.1 (build 1.8.0_302-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.302.08.1 (build 25.302-b08, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was trying to use

```
implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.21.0'
```

to map the apache Pair class but getting exactly the same error as you.

Through trial and error I discovered that adding to gradle

```
implementation 'org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.1.0.Final'
```

the error disappeared and the application started.

I use

```
azul java-1.8.0_322; 
spring boot version 2.1.4.RELEASE; 
hibernate version 5.6.9.Final
```

I am convinced that the error was caused by incompatible library versions.